# problems in jquery toggle function in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have written the following jquery in my rails application in a file called custom.js. I have written this to toggle open a text box on clicking a tick box.

```
$(document).on('page:load', function(){ 

$(".category_check").on("change", function(){
    //alert("test")
    // alert()
    //alert($(this).data('category'))

    $("#" + $(this).data('category')).toggle();

  });

  $(".quality_check").on("change", function(){
  //alert("test")
    // alert()
    //alert($(this).data('category'))
    $("#" + $(this).data('quality')).toggle();

  });

  $(".duration_check").on("change", function(){
  //alert("test")
    // alert()
    //alert($(this).data('category'))
    $("#" + $(this).data('duration')).toggle();

  });

    $(".delivery_time_check").on("change", function(){
  //alert("test")
    // alert()
    //alert($(this).data('category'))
    $("#" + $(this).data('delivery_time')).toggle();

  });
});
```

Here is the html part of the code:

```
  <label>Categories</label>
  <% ClipCategory.all.each do |category| %>
      <%= form_tag "update_amount", :remote => :true do %>
      <div class="span12">
        <div class="category_check pull-left" data-category="category_text_<%= category.id %>">
          <%= check_box_tag "category", 1, ( @performer.clip_category_ids.include?(category.id) ? "checked" : false ), :class => "pull-left" %>  
          <%= label_tag "category", category.name, :class => "pull-left category_label" %> 
        </div>

        <% amount_val = ClipCategoryPerformer.where("clip_category_id = ? AND performer_id = ?", category.id, current_user.performer.id ).first %>
        <div id="category_text_<%= category.id%>" class="category_text span10 pull-right">
         <% if amount_val %>
          <%= number_field_tag "amount", @amount, :class => "pull-left input-medium", :value => amount_val.amount %>
          <% else %>
          <%= number_field_tag "amount", @amount, :class => "pull-left input-medium", :value => nil %>
          <% end %>
          <%= hidden_field_tag "category_id", category.id %>
          <%= submit_tag "Update" %>
         </div>
      </div>
        <br />
      <% end %>

  <% end %>

</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
<% Quality.all.each do |quality| %>
  <%= form_tag "update_quality_amount", :remote => :true do %>
  <div class="span12">
    <div class="quality_check pull-left" data-quality="quality_text_<%= quality.id %>">
      <%= check_box_tag "quality", 1, ( @performer.quality_ids.include?(quality.id) ? "checked" : false ), :class => "pull-left" %>  
      <%= label_tag "quality", quality.name, :class => "pull-left category_label" %> 
    </div>

    <% amount_val = ClipCategoryPerformer.where("clip_category_id = ? AND performer_id = ?", quality.id, current_user.performer.id ).first %>
    <div id="quality_text_<%= quality.id %>" class="quality_text span10 pull-right">
      <% if amount_val %>
          <%= number_field_tag "amount", @amount, :class => "pull-left input-medium", :value => amount_val.amount %>
          <% else %>
          <%= number_field_tag "amount", @amount, :class => "pull-left input-medium", :value => nil %>
          <% end %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag "quality_id", quality.id %>
      <%= submit_tag "Update" %>
     </div>
  </div>
    <br />
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane" id="tab5">
  <% Duration.all.each do |duration| %>
  <%= form_tag "update_duration_amount", :remote => :true do %>
  <div class="span12">
    <div class="duration_check pull-left" data-duration="duration_text_<%= duration.id %>">
      <%= check_box_tag "duration", 1, ( @performer.duration_ids.include?(duration.id) ? "checked" : false ), :class => "pull-left" %>  
      <%= label_tag "duration", duration.time, :class => "pull-left duration_label" %> 
    </div>
    <% amount_val = ClipCategoryPerformer.where("clip_category_id = ? AND performer_id = ?", duration.id, current_user.performer.id ).first %>
    <div id="duration_text_<%= duration.id %>" class="duration_text span10 pull-right">
      <% if amount_val %>
          <%= number_field_tag "amount", @amount, :class => "pull-left input-medium", :value => amount_val.amount %>
          <% else %>
          <%= number_field_tag "amount", @amount, :class => "pull-left input-medium", :value => nil %>
          <% end %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag "duration_id", duration.id %>
      <%= submit_tag "Update" %>
     </div>
  </div>
    <br />
      <% end %>
  <% end %>

</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab6">
  <% DeliveryTime.all.each do |delivery_time| %>
  <%= form_tag "update_delivery_time_amount", :remote => :true do %>
  <div class="span12">
    <div class="delivery_time_check pull-left" data-delivery_time="delivery_time_text_<%= delivery_time.id %>">
      <%= check_box_tag "delivery_time", 1, ( @performer.delivery_time_ids.include?(delivery_time.id) ? "checked" : false ), :class => "pull-left" %>  
      <%= label_tag "delivery_time", delivery_time.duration, :class => "pull-left delivery_time_label" %> 
    </div>
    <% amount_val = ClipCategoryPerformer.where("clip_category_id = ? AND performer_id = ?", delivery_time.id, current_user.performer.id ).first %>
    <div id="delivery_time_text_<%= delivery_time.id %>" class="delivery_time_text span10 pull-right">
      <% if amount_val %>
          <%= number_field_tag "amount", @amount, :class => "pull-left input-medium", :value => amount_val.amount %>
          <% else %>
          <%= number_field_tag "amount", @amount, :class => "pull-left input-medium", :value => nil %>
          <% end %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag "delivery_time_id", delivery_time.id %>
      <%= submit_tag "Update" %>
     </div>
  </div>
    <br />
      <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

When I click the click the any check box other than first in the title instead of the checkbox itself the first one gets checked and not the one I clicked. The check box is retained if I refresh the page and when I uncheck it only the text box is toggling and when I check it, it vanishes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which jquery version you use

Comment: I am using jquery-rails. I am using it without any version number so it is the latest. It uses jQuery 1.10.2.

Comment: in this toggle not works because in new version of jquery toggle is removed

Comment: what should I replace toggle with???

Comment: apply custom code on click with if else